# Unable to click on the submit button with xpath and classname using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath

This is the html code :

```
...
<div class="span_3_of_4"> 
  <p class="text_popup"> Dont Have an Account? | 
    <a class="fancybox" href="#load_box">Signup</a> 
  </p> 
</div> 
<div class="span_1_of_4" align="center"> 
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</div> 
</div> 
</form> 
</div> 
<script src="js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Its a submit button. I am trying to automate a registration for using selenium webdriver. There are no ids or names as such for this button. Hence i tried with xpath (taken from firebug) `.//*[@id='load_form']/div/div[2]/input` and `classname` - `button`.

Yet the following error was being thrown `Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted withCommand duration or timeout: 428 milliseconds`.
Please suggest as to how can i ever overcome this error and be able to click on the "submit" button.

Selenium Version - 2.44

Comment: Could you add the code you've written for this
?

Comment: e=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/div/div[2]/input")); This the code that i had written for identifying the elemnt i also used By.className("button")

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='load_box']/form[@id='load_form']//input[@class='button' and @type='submit']"))
```

Problem was that there are several `form` elements with "load_form" on the site and the first one is hidden! that's why you need a more specific xpath like the one above.

Comment: aded folwing cd   e=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='load_form']//input[@class='button' and @type='submit']"));
e.click();                                                                                 The same error is being shown. Ther's only one Submit btn n the page. Html is: <div class="span_3_of_4">
<p class="text_popup">
Dont Have an Account? | 
<a class="fancybox" href="#load_box">Signup</a>
</p>
</div>
<div class="span_1_of_4" align="center">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"/>

Comment: please update your question with the html that also contains the element with id = "load_form" and also your selenium code!

Comment: <form id="load_form" class="ajaxlogin" method="post" action="ajax.php">
<input type="hidden" value="login" name="action"/>
<h3>Login</h3>
<img id="loader1" width="20" height="20" style="display:none;" src="images/loader.gif"/>
<p id="alert1"/>
<fieldset>
<fieldset>
<div class="bottom row">
<div class="span_3_of_4">
<div class="span_1_of_4" align="center">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>

Comment: e=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/div/div[2]/input"));
     e.click();

Comment: it seems that the type of load_form is hidden. how can that be made visible so that i will be able to click on the submit button?

Comment: analyzed the site and updated my answer, you need to be more specific in the xpath, because there are several "load_form" elements

Comment: glad to be of service! if it helped you, you can upvote and mark as the correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue a lot, and one thing that normally solves the problem is switching frames. With python I think it's something like `driver.switch_to_frame('frame')` I may be wrong there with the syntax but definitely try that out